# Spring Tool Suite - log files getting exported

Tags: spring-tool-suite

My company doesn't allow copying of any files from its intranet to the outside world. However, after I installed Spring Tool Suite, it's automatically trying to sent some log files outside and I keep getting email from my company's internal system that tracks this kind of activity.

How do I switch this off so that no files can exported outside automatically?

Comment: what version of STS do you use? Since we don't include the automated usage data reporting anymore and we also excluded the Eclipse Mars Error Reporting, I am wondering what sending data here. Or did you download Eclipse Mars and installed STS on top yourself?

Comment: Spring Tool Suite 

Version: 3.6.2.RELEASE
Build Id: 201410091308
Platform: Eclipse Luna SR1 (4.4.1)

btw, I didn't installed the Mars Reporting. Please help!

Comment: you can go to the preferences and disable the usage data reporting there (take a look at Spring -> Spring UAA)

Comment: Disabling UAA doesn't work. However I realized the frequency of the report showing data been exported has reduced.

Comment: You could even uninstall UAA completely from STS. But if disabling this doesn't work, I am not sure what piece is sending log files or usage data. This would need a deeper analysis. Can you tell me where the log data is being send to?

Answer (score 0):

If you have control over your firewall (at least to an outgoing packet filter on your workstation), you could simply forbid it in for your software.